# Error receiver-[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTeamDetails' of undefined

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

Iam trying to build a bot with microsoft bot framework with nodejs

When i use the below code i get an error-
[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTeamDetails' of undefined

```
const { ActivityHandler,TeamsInfo} = require('botbuilder');

export class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
            const teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext);
            if (teamDetails) {
                await turnContext.sendActivity(`The group ID is: ${teamDetails.aadGroupId}`);
            } else {
                await turnContext.sendActivity('This message did not come from a channel in a team.');
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your `TeamsInfo` is `undefined`

Comment: How and where to define? I don't understand.

Comment: Then how do you used this line `const { ActivityHandler,TeamsInfo} = require('botbuilder');` in your code??

Comment: Yes i have used that line ,that means it is defined right? What i did not understand is when you mentioned its  not defined .could you please elaborate .

Comment: What is your version of BotBuilder? Could you also post the version you use in your package.json? (and do a new `npm install` just to be sure).

Comment: Version being used from package.json file-
    "dependencies": {
        "@microsoft/recognizers-text-data-types-timex-expression": "^1.1.4",
        "@nodelib/fs.stat": "^2.0.3",
        "applicationinsights": "^1.6.0",
        "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "botbuilder": "^4.5.3",
        "botbuilder-ai": "~4.5.1",
        "botbuilder-azure": "^4.5.3",
        "botbuilder-dialogs": "^4.5.3",
        "botbuilder-teams": "^0.2.7",
        "botbuilder-testing": "~4.5.1"
        },

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are still using `botbuilder` 4.5.3, but [support for Teams has been added in 4.6.0](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/releases/tag/4.6.0). When you update your packages to (at least) 4.6, it will work.

```
npm update
```

I see that you are also still using `botbuilder-teams` which is deprecated and shows the following deprecation notice.

> The functionality of this SDK has been incorporated into the core Bot Framework SDK as of v4.6. Upgrade your Bot Framework SDK to access Teams-specific functions.

You could uninstall `botbuilder-teams` if you are not using any functionality from that package anymore.

```
npm uninstall botbuilder-teams
```

Comment: Thanks Mick, upgrading to the newer version resolved the issue :)

Comment: Great to hear! Would be great if you could accept my answer. :-)